# How to fix broken CSV file where column values are not formatted properly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a weird format that I am having difficulty formatting it to a desired format. I just need the columns `first_name`, `last_name`, `domain`, `Email`, `Verification` and `status` but am not sure how to remove it when it is in this format.

```
,first_name,last_name,domain,Email,Score,Verification status,Source 1,Source 2,Source 3,Source 4,Source 5,Source 6,Source 7,Source 8,Source 9,Source 10,Source 11,Source 12,Source 13,Source 14,Source 15,Source 16,Source 17,Source 18,Source 19,Source 20,Source 21,Source 22,Source 23,Source 24,Source 25,Source 26,Source 27,Source 28,Source 29,Source 30
25   138,Ethan,Gach,kotaku.com,ethan.gach@kotaku.co...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
79   535,Carla,Mozée,businessinsider.com,cmozee@bus...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
114  814,Neil,Irwin,nytimes.com,neil.irwin@nytimes....
```

#### Expected output:

```
  first_name last_name               domain                       Email Score Verification status
0      Carla     Mozée  businessinsider.com  cmozee@businessinsider.com    99               valid
```

#### Sample of the dataframe as a dictionary:

```
{',first_name,last_name,domain,Email,Score,Verification status,Source 1,Source 2,Source 3,Source 4,Source 5,Source 6,Source 7,Source 8,Source 9,Source 10,Source 11,Source 12,Source 13,Source 14,Source 15,Source 16,Source 17,Source 18,Source 19,Source 20,Source 21,Source 22,Source 23,Source 24,Source 25,Source 26,Source 27,Source 28,Source 29,Source 30': {25: '138,Ethan,Gach,kotaku.com,ethan.gach@kotaku.com,99,valid,http://kotaku.com/new-mod-lets-you-play-game-boy-advance-games-in-hd-on-a-1830834944,http://compete.kotaku.com/the-weekend-in-esports-boston-counter-strike-party-1822479309,http://kotaku.com/madden-nfl-21-will-be-the-first-in-the-series-on-steam-1844050894,http://kotaku.com/gogs-mysterious-curation-process-rejected-opus-magnum-1821843050,http://kotaku.com/a-dramatic-podcast-fills-in-the-gaps-of-fallout-76s-bro-1842064555,http://kotaku.com/electronic-arts-says-its-customers-just-arent-that-inte-1836862047,http://compete.kotaku.com/the-weekend-in-esports-counter-strike-pokemon-and-su-1821353758,http://compete.kotaku.com/brazilians-prove-unstoppable-at-australian-counter-stri-1794995886,http://compete.kotaku.com/street-fighter-pro-goes-looking-for-an-energy-drink-mid-1818489146,http://dustinhawkfarmily.blogspot.com/2016/09,http://compete.kotaku.com/virtus-pro-seizes-top-spot-in-dota-2-pro-circuit-1823310035,http://deniseuncensored.blogspot.com/2016/05,http://destinyisbae.com/deaf-destiny-player-petitions-bungie-for-captioning,http://destinyisbae.com/destiny-player-destroys-latest-raid-boss-all-by-himself,http://kinja.com/ethangach/following,http://kinja.com/ethangach/followers,http://cosplay.kotaku.com/police-mistake-fallout-cosplay-for-bomb-1794353299,http://cosplay.kotaku.com/tracer-and-emily-cosplay-celebrates-romantic-overwatch-1790505557,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  79: '535,Carla,Mozée,businessinsider.com,cmozee@businessinsider.com,99,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  114: '814,Neil,Irwin,nytimes.com,neil.irwin@nytimes.com,96,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  435: '5308,Alyssa,Therrien,dailyhive.com,alyssa@dailyhive.com,96,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  478: '6007,Bruce,Kamich,thestreet.com,bruce.kamich@thestreet.com,97,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  494: '6255,Zach,Brendza,triblive.com,zbrendza@triblive.com,96,valid,http://triblive.com/news/all-stories,http://triblive.com/author/zach-brendza,http://triblive.com/aande/movies-tv/mighty-ducks-fly-together-for-reunion-at-nhl-game-secret-project,http://triblive.com/business/technology/gillette-ad-brings-mixed-response-400k-youtube-dislikes,http://triblive.com/aande/movies-tv/taylor-swift-confirms-cats-role-on-instagram,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  518: '6719,Bernhard,Warner,fortune.com,bernhard.warner@fortune.com,96,valid,http://asherradio.com/disease-recession-war-games-why-none-of-it-seems-to-count-as-bad-news-for-todays-investors,http://mimicnews.com/could-hong-kong-tensions-sink-the-global-stocks-rally,http://mainstreetalerts.com/2020/01/31/the-coronavirus-is-already-disrupting-the-global-supply-chain-starting-with-these-commodities,http://mainstreetalerts.com/2020/03/16/global-markets-tumble-despite-the-feds-best-efforts-to-restore-confidence,http://mainstreetalerts.com/2020/03/17/global-markets-remain-choppy-after-mondays-historic-plunge,http://isreally.com/2020/02/21/looking-more-probable-analysts-up-the-odds-of-a-markets-correction-as-coronavirus-fears-surge,http://isreally.com/tag/bear-market,http://isreally.com/tag/bull-sheet,http://isreally.com/tag/nasdaq,http://isreally.com/tag/sp-500,http://fortunemediakit.com/editorial-bios,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  534: '6965,Clarence,Page,chicagotribune.com,cpage@chicagotribune.com,98,valid,http://chicagotribune.com/columns/clarence-page/ct-page-police-trump-speech-brutality-perspec-0802-jm-20170801-story.html,http://latimes.com:443/newsletters/politics/ct-page-portland-attack-hate-trump-perspec-0531-jm-20170530-story.html,http://chicagotribune.com/columns/clarence-page/ct-column-truth-fake-news-literacy-page-20201126-rpzogqv2fvdnnmzh6x4py7oblu-story.html,http://chicagotribune.com/columns/clarence-page/ct-column-trump-hawley-twitter-first-amendment-page-20210112-qdt6ehyk3fecnbha5lw4ginwa4-story.html,http://chicagotribune.com/columns/clarence-page/ct-perspec-page-caravan-donald-trump-judge-jon-tigar-1125-20181121-story.html,http://chicagotribune.com/news/columnists/chinews-clarence-page-20130507-staff.html,http://businessandcommunitypartners.blogspot.com/2015/08/i-dont-believe-arc-of-justice-bends-our.html,http://businessandcommunitypartners.blogspot.com/2015/08,http://arcamax.com/politics/fromtheleft/clarencepage/s-2361828-p2,http://arcamax.com/politics/fromtheleft/clarencepage/s-2368961,http://arcamax.com/politics/fromtheleft/clarencepage/s-2314283,http://arcamax.com/politics/fromtheleft/clarencepage/s-2357041,http://destee.com/threads/rachel-dolezals-naturalhair-politics.87634,http://arcamax.com/politics/fromtheleft/clarencepage/s-2302572,http://newsday.com/opinion/commentary/dems-lawsuit-not-as-nutty-as-it-sounds-1.18269124,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  558: '7730,Brenden,Rearick,investorplace.com,brearick@investorplace.com,95,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,',
  592: '8639,Ian,Chee,lowyat.net,ian@lowyat.net,98,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'}}
```

#### Sample from the original CSV file:

```
,first_name,last_name,domain,Email,Score,Verification status,Source 1,Source 2,Source 3,Source 4,Source 5,Source 6,Source 7,Source 8,Source 9,Source 10,Source 11,Source 12,Source 13,Source 14,Source 15,Source 16,Source 17,Source 18,Source 19,Source 20,Source 21,Source 22,Source 23,Source 24,Source 25,Source 26,Source 27,Source 28,Source 29,Source 30
0,Jon,Levine,nypost.com,jlevine@nypost.com,87,accept_all,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,Sujata,Rao,reuters.com,sujata.rao@reuters.com,94,accept_all,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,Tony,Dokoupil,cbsnews.com,dokoupilt@cbsnews.com,87,accept_all,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,Pippa,Stevens,cnbc.com,philippa.stevens@cnbc.com,94,unknown,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,Clarissa-jan,Lim,buzzfeednews.com,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,Thomas,Franck,cnbc.com,thomas.franck@cnbc.com,92,unknown,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
7,Matt,Phillips,nytimes.com,matt.phillips@nytimes.com,97,valid,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,Jake,Johnson,commondreams.org,jake@commondreams.org,90,accept_all,http://portside.org/node/19308/printable/print,http://beatnikmalcontent.blogspot.com/2019,http://beatnikmalcontent.blogspot.com/2019/02,http://beatnikmalcontent.blogspot.com/2019/02/socialism-is-more-popular-than-you.html,http://portside.org/2019-02-07/socialism-more-popular-you-think-mr-president-ocasio-cortez-says-trump-attack-shows,http://commondreams.org/key-staff,http://24ahead.com/u/johnsonjakep,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11,Graig,Graziosi,independent.co.uk,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample from the original CSV file?

Comment: So this is what you have inside the text file? Including the `{` and `79:` etc...

Comment: Sorry I included a sample from the CSV file now @AndrejKesely

Comment: Line 9 (Jake Johnson) seems to have too many values (thus throwing ParserError). Setting error_bad_lines to False, the rest of data seems to read fine. Cannot replicate what you get in your DataFrame (pandas 1.2.4)

Comment: I'd loop through your date, split on commas, and then only pull out the columns you need from the mapped dictionary. I could give you an coding example if you'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file with `pandas.read_csv()` with `error_bad_lines=False`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
df = df[['first_name', 'last_name', 'domain', 'Email', 'Verification status']]
```

This will output:

|  | first_name | last_name | domain | Email | Verification status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jon | Levine | nypost.com | jlevine@nypost.com | accept_all |
| 1 | Sujata | Rao | reuters.com | sujata.rao@reuters.com | accept_all |
| 2 | Tony | Dokoupil | cbsnews.com | dokoupilt@cbsnews.com | accept_all |
| 3 | Pippa | Stevens | cnbc.com | philippa.stevens@cnbc.com | unknown |
| 4 | Clarissa-jan | Lim | buzzfeednews.com | nan | nan |
| 5 | Thomas | Franck | cnbc.com | thomas.franck@cnbc.com | unknown |
| 6 | Matt | Phillips | nytimes.com | matt.phillips@nytimes.com | valid |
| 7 | Graig | Graziosi | independent.co.uk | nan | nan |

You can save it with `df.to_csv('filename.csv')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `usecols=`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_data.txt", usecols=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     first_name last_name             domain                      Email Verification status
0           Jon    Levine         nypost.com         jlevine@nypost.com          accept_all
1        Sujata       Rao        reuters.com     sujata.rao@reuters.com          accept_all
2          Tony  Dokoupil        cbsnews.com      dokoupilt@cbsnews.com          accept_all
3         Pippa   Stevens           cnbc.com  philippa.stevens@cnbc.com             unknown
4  Clarissa-jan       Lim   buzzfeednews.com                        NaN                 NaN
5        Thomas    Franck           cnbc.com     thomas.franck@cnbc.com             unknown
6          Matt  Phillips        nytimes.com  matt.phillips@nytimes.com               valid
7          Jake   Johnson   commondreams.org      jake@commondreams.org          accept_all
8         Graig  Graziosi  independent.co.uk                        NaN                 NaN
```